# How to set multiple fonts in one line in QAction (Qt)?

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to make the text in QAction have two different style of text. For example, 
*timmy*.duncan, i.e. italic style in the first word and normal style in the second word. Is it possible?

Comment: **QAction** is provides an abstract action that can be used with other widgets. Usually, developer will add **QAction** to existing menu or widget (like buttons etc). It is a question on how you are using **QActions** in your code.

If I do remember it correctly, it was possible to set different font, when **QAction** was used together with menu. Can you provide an MCV (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable) example?

Comment: See no way to do it easily. Maybe you have to override `QWidgetAction` or another class to implement such feature. But why do you need it?

Comment: Yes. It seems that I have to override QWidgetAction.